# Returning Functions or Values: recursive python functions

Tags: python, recursion

Would anyone be willing to explain why the first does not work, but the second does?

In the first, the function calculates the final, adjusted value...

```
# returns None
def _pareRotation(degs):
    if degs > 360:          
        _pareRotation(degs - 360)
    else:
        print "returning %s" % degs
        return degs
```

...but returns `None`:

```
print _pareRotation(540)
>> returning 180
>> None
```

However, if we flip things a bit and return the function...

```
# returns expected results
def _pareRotation(degs):
    if degs < 360:          
        print "returning %s" % degs     
        return degs
    else:
        return _pareRotation(degs - 360)
```

...it works as expected:

```
print _pareRotation(540)
>> returning 180
>> 180
```

Mostly, wondering what causes that `None` to get ejected from the recursive loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not *returning* in the first case:

```
def _pareRotation(degs):
    if degs > 360:          
        _pareRotation(degs - 360)
#      ^
```

Comment: There should be a canonical question for this if there isn't already. This kind of recursion failure comes up 5 times a day on this tag at least.

Comment: Good grief, and there it is.  Thank you.  I agree @Two-BitAlchemist, but there might be some subtle variance in the questions.  I had trouble grokking the idea that the target variable -- let's say `final_degs` -- would in a sense "become" the recursive function.  When I run `final_degs = _pareRotation(540)`, and I print or use `final_degs`, I'm actually using a variable that has gone through a few transformations (function to int). Is that an accurate way of thinking about it?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you aren't returning in the first case, and also I think it should be %d, for int.